# How do you add multiple spawn events in a command in Minecraft bedrock edition

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've been messing around with spawn events in commands in Minecraft bedrock edition and I was wondering if there was a way to have multiple spawn events an example like this

`/summon creeper ~ ~ ~ "minecraft:become_charged, minecraft:start_exploding_forced"`

I cant seem to find a way how and I was wondering if there was a way how I could?

Comment: I don't know anything about these "spawn events" in MCBE, but I would try `", "` or `" "` instead of `, `. Maybe you could also try putting it all into curly brackets (`{}`) or rectangular brackets (`[]`). You currently have one single string, which happens to contain a comma, but that comma has no meaning to the main command.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can only specify one spawn event.

From [Commands/summon on the Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/summon#Arguments) (emphasis mine):

> `spawnEvent: string`: basic_string
>
> Must be either a single word (no spaces) or a quoted string.
> Specifies **the in-game event** for the entity. Should be a spawn event (event name for entities in behavior pack).

This implies that mobs can only have one spawn event.